# База данных, андроид

Tags: android, база-данных, android-fragment

Нужно реализовать в программе сохранение данных, введённых пользователем во Фрагментах. Попробовал самостоятельно написать DBHelper из обучалки Start Android. Постарался как можно точнее привести тамошнюю таблицу, к своей, но не могу разобраться, почему при нажатии кнопки Save программа вылетает и не сохраняет данные.

Вот код активности, в которой находится кнопка и фрагмент:

```
package com.example.alexey.finalprojectalexeymushailov;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SecondaryActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements         
View.OnClickListener {
DBHelper dbHelper;
fragmentA frgOne;
fragmentB frgTwo;
FragmentTransaction frgTransaction;
int currentlyFragment;
Button butClear, butSave;
EditText misparRehev, shemEhida, sugTipul, kamutKilometrim, date;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    //basic
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                 //code
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondary);        //in android

    //here I find buttons and editTexts+Switches via findViewById and apply listener to them
    butSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);   //save button
    butSave.setOnClickListener(this);                //save listener
    butClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear); //clear button
    butClear.setOnClickListener(this);               //clear listener
    //here are editTexts for fragmentA
    misparRehev = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMisparRehev);
    shemEhida = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editShemEhida);
    sugTipul = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSugTipul);
    kamutKilometrim = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editKilometrim);
    date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDate);
    //here are editTexts for fragmentA ^


    //here I initialize my fragments for fragment manager so I could use it for change between fragments
    frgOne = new fragmentA();
    frgTwo = new fragmentB();
    //this code makes fragment one turn on immediatly when activity 2 is on the screen
    frgTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    frgTransaction.add(R.id.frameLayout, frgOne);
    currentlyFragment = 1;    //this is variable for code, that makes program know which fragment is on the screen right now
    frgTransaction.commit();

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);  // here I initialize my database and call for it's class
}
public void onClickChange(View v){           //this is onClick for changing between activities
    if (currentlyFragment == 1){   //1 is first fragment
        frgTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        frgTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, frgTwo);
        currentlyFragment = 2;
        frgTransaction.commit();
    }
    else if (currentlyFragment == 2){  //2 is second fragment
        frgTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        frgTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, frgOne);
        currentlyFragment = 1;
        frgTransaction.commit();
    }


}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {    // this is onClick function for saving data to database in SQLite
    String rehev = misparRehev.getText().toString();            ///
    String ehida = shemEhida.getText().toString();              /////
    String tipul = sugTipul.getText().toString();               /////// here we get entered in EditText data
    String kmetres = kamutKilometrim.getText().toString();      /////
    String taarih = date.getText().toString();                  ///

    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnSave:
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_MISPAR_REHEV, rehev);            ///
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_SHEM_EHIDA, ehida);              /////
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_SUG_TIPUL, tipul);               /////// here I put data in DB TABLE
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_KAMUT_KILOMETRES, kmetres);      /////
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_TAARHIH, taarih);                ///

            database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_ONE, null, contentValues);
            break;

    }
}
```

}

Вот код DBHelper (класса, в котором я реализовал таблицу):

```
package com.example.alexey.finalprojectalexeymushailov;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  //myDatabase version
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase";   //DB name
public static final String TABLE_ONE= "myTable1";               //DB TABLE name


public static final String KEY_MISPAR_REHEV = "_id";
public static final String KEY_SHEM_EHIDA = "_id";
public static final String KEY_SUG_TIPUL= "_id";
public static final String KEY_KAMUT_KILOMETRES = "_id";
public static final String KEY_TAARHIH = "_id";




public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION)   ;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_ONE +
            "(" + KEY_MISPAR_REHEV + " integer primary key, "
            + KEY_SHEM_EHIDA + " text," + KEY_SUG_TIPUL + " text,"
            + KEY_KAMUT_KILOMETRES + " text," + KEY_TAARHIH + " text" + ")");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_ONE);

    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

Comment: Ошибка, которую мне выдаёт компилятор:  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.alexey.finalprojectalexeymushailov, PID: 4791
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.alexey.finalprojectalexeymushailov.SecondaryActivity.onClick(SecondaryActivity.java:72)

Comment: У вас проблема не с базой данных, а с фрагментами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кто же так делает?

```
//here are editTexts for fragmentA
misparRehev = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMisparRehev);
shemEhida = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editShemEhida);
sugTipul = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSugTipul);
kamutKilometrim = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editKilometrim);
date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDate);
//here are editTexts for fragmentA ^
```

Нельзя из `onCreate` активити найти UI элемент фрагмента.
У вас тут все пять `null`, вот и `NullPointerException` в итоге.

Comment: Вы не могли бы, уточнить, как именно нужно находить элементы фрагмента в данном случае? Я едва пару месяцев на Android, и еще не разобрался со всем синтаксисом.

Comment: Для вас самый простой вариант, это находить EditText в самом методе onClick. И проверять на null перед использованием.

Comment: В идеале нужно не смешивать, если UI элемент относится к фрагменту, значить он должен с ним взаимодействовать, а не активити. Иными словами, надо продумать интерфейс взаимодействия между активити и ее фрагментами. Официальный туториал к этому и призывает: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html